# How to remove the color indication to the left in PHPStorm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

How can I remove this? It's very annoying and it looks like an error:

http://i.imm.io/1dwm7.jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Settings (Preferences on Mac)
2. Type "color preview" in search box (top left corner)

[image]

**P.S.**
Re-opening project (at very least, the editor tab) quite likely will be required.

Comment: Yes, a restart was necessary. Thanks!